# Why does Flow complain when I listen for XHR errors?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Try this in [tryflow](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAHgCwE4wLwzAUwO4wBoCyAMgBJRQAOASpgI4Cum0AFAJQDcAUJ4kgHQBDACZCAogDdMYKEQCW0KZiTMA5EqQgkKgDQxm6gFwxRSDUlZoAfDADenGDFCQQAG0x8XIAOareMAGYCsm5COjDqHJwAvpFAA):

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener('error', (err: Error) => {
  console.log('xhr failed', err);
});
```

Flow gives this cryptic error:

```
call of method `addEventListener`. Function cannot be called on any member of intersection type intersection
```

The complaint goes away if I don't take the `err` parameter. But I need that parameter.

I've tried with and without annotating the `err`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The argument for an `error` event handler is an `Event` object, not an `Error` object. Do

```
xhr.addEventListener('error', (err: Event) => {
```